# is it possible to refresh your browser window 1000 times in a row really fast in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried it but it didn't seem to work. For what I am doing there needs to be a lot of refreshing, but not so fast that it's going to stall the browser obviously.

```
<script>

for (var i=0; i < 10000; i++)
{ 
     window.location.reload(); 
}           
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: This is going to be INFINITE refresh, because the state of the loop doesn't persist.

Comment: This will cause all sorts of problems if successful. It will kill the browser, it will kill the network connection, it will hurt your server...

Comment: its for a game, so I have to refresh really quickly.

Comment: @OutofSpace That doesn't help matters.  Js doesn't need to refresh to manipulate the contents of the browser.  You would do well to clarify your question.

Comment: Are you trying to cheat in a game that gives bonuses each page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible, to refresh complete page! as it lost the state on refresh it goes to infinite loop, Yes you can refresh a particular portion of a page with ajax call.

`Truly speaking don't know why someone need to do this`.

Comment: you can set a refresh counter in cookie so it's technically possible.

Comment: @RayCheng Or on the server side too.

Comment: Code like this I think just gets ignored by browsers anyway, because they consider it malicious. Which it is, I wouldn't want it running in my browser. That is not the purpose, though.